# Include and exclude a text in sql / php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi please help me with this 
I dont know how to preform a search query to exclude a text from search .
I have 2 search fields .
**include text1** /
**exclude text 2** / &
**search button**

**note : the second text field is optional**

1. I want a way to detect what fileld is entered with php and preform an action
2. I dont know how to exclude something from sql query / PHP

Thank you !

Comment: your query will be something like this: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE '%includedtext%' AND fieldname NOT LIKE '%excludedtext%'` but I think, you should start from the basics. At here stack overflow we help if you stuck somewhere and you have some code.

Comment: You should read up on basic [form handling in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) for testing which field is entered.

Comment: thank you ! but what will happen if '%excludedtext%'  is not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$text1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['text1']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text1 = '$text1'";
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];
//modify sql only if text2 was filled out
if($text2) {
    $text2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $text2);
    $sql .= " AND text2 = '$text2'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can fix:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table
WHERE Column LIKE '%text1%'
AND Column NOT LIKE '%text2%';
```